How to set Helm Argument —create-namespace in ArgoCD Applications Definition
I have try to add cert-Manager via Helm through ArgoCD applicaton Definition. I set the Namenspace value for the Helm chart. And if i sync the following definition i get an error because the namespace cert-manager dose not exists.
    apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: Application
    metadata:
      name: cert-manager
      namespace: argocd
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: 'https://charts.jetstack.io'
        targetRevision: v1.15.1
        chart: cert-manager
        helm:
          parameters:
            - name: crds.enabled
              value: 'true'
            - name: startupapicheck.timeout
              value: 5m
            - name: namespace
              value: cert-manager
      destination:
        server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
      syncPolicy:
        syncOptions:
          - CreateNamespace=true

Does anyone know how I can pass the Helm Argument create-namespace to do this?
Many greetings and thanks

The namespace you're trying to create needs to be in spec.destination.namespace in addition to whatever the helm chart is expecting.
https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-options/#create-namespace
"The example above shows how an Argo CD Application can be configured so it will create the namespace specified in spec.destination.namespace if it doesn't exist already. ..."
    apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
    kind: Application
    metadata:
      name: cert-manager
      namespace: argocd
    spec:
      project: default
      source:
        repoURL: 'https://charts.jetstack.io'
        targetRevision: v1.15.1
        chart: cert-manager
        helm:
          parameters:
            - name: crds.enabled
              value: 'true'
            - name: startupapicheck.timeout
              value: 5m
            - name: namespace
              value: cert-manager
      destination:
        server: 'https://kubernetes.default.svc'
        namespace: cert-manager
      syncPolicy:
        syncOptions:
          - CreateNamespace=true


Sometimes you can't see the forest because of the trees. Thanks.
